# How to avoid more than three webpack bundled in JS files

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm using Vue framework with webpack, and in my project I have more than 10 `node_modules` like `lodash`, `vuex,vue-router` and more.

My problem is after I build my project it showed 13 JS files, but here I want to restrict to only two or three files.

Inside my `/dist` folder

[image]

`package.json`

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production"
  },
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
    // entry: './src/build.js',

   
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "main.js",
        library: "$",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
      },
      
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader'],
              
            },
           
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
   


}
```

1. How can I avoid more than 3 files in my `dist` folder?
2. How can I rename those 3 files in my `dist` folder? For example `1.main`, `2.main`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**maxChunk**

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1, // disable creating additional chunks
    })
],
```